next-auth types are not taken into account
I am using next-auth in my Next.js project with TypeScript.
My tsconfig.json is the following:
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "lib": ["dom", "dom.iterable", "esnext"],
    "allowJs": true,
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    "strict": true,
    "noEmit": true,
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "module": "esnext",
    "moduleResolution": "bundler",
    "resolveJsonModule": true,
    "isolatedModules": true,
    "jsx": "preserve",
    "incremental": true,
    "plugins": [
      {
        "name": "next"
      }
    ],
    "paths": {
      "@/*": ["./*"]
    }
  },
  "include": [
    "next-env.d.ts",
    "**/*.ts",
    "**/*.tsx",
    ".next/types/**/*.ts",
    "./types/*.ts"
  ],
  "exclude": ["node_modules"]
}

My next-auth.d.ts (located at project_root/types/) is
// eslint-disable-next-line
import NextAuth, { DefaultSession } from "next-auth";
// eslint-disable-next-line
import { JWT } from "next-auth/jwt";

declare module "next-auth" {
  interface Session {
    user: {
      ethAddress: string;
    };
  }
  interface User {
    ethAddress: string;
  }
}

declare module "next-auth/jwt" {
  interface JWT {
    ethAddress: string;
  }
}

I am trying to implement authorization. There are two signs that my types are not set up correctly.

In the authorize function, I am returning an object that looks like {ethAddress: string}, however, I get the following error:

Property 'id' is missing in type '{ ethAddress: string; }' but required in type 'User'.

Note that I am not completely sure if this error is shown because of types misconfiguration or because it is mandatory for an id attribute to exist even if you don't declare it in your User type.

My callbacks are not typed automatically. Based on the docs and some next-auth + TypeScript examples, I should not have to manually indicate the type of callback arguments, however, having the following code:

callbacks: {
    async jwt({ token, user }) {
      if (user) {
        token.ethAddress = user.ethAddress;
      }
      return token;
    },
    async session({ session, token }) {
      session.user.address = token.address;
      return session;
    },
  },

All of the arguments show an error similar to:
Binding element 'token' implicitly has an 'any' type.

I made sure to restart the TS Server multiple times and restarted VS Code, but nothing worked.
Do you have any suggestions?
Edit 1
I also added "typeRoots": ["./types"], in my TypeScript configuration but nothing happened.
